# php Switch/case doesn't work

Tags: php, html, switch-statement

I tried to find my answer in the other switch/case question. But i don't find the solution.

I got a switch that split my date values in 4 different quarters. 
But when i want to print it out, it doesn't work. I don't know what i'm doing wrong.

is this a typo or?

Thanks in advance.

**MY CODE**

```
while (odbc_fetch_row($result)) { // while there are rows 
    $overweight = odbc_result($result, "Weight1") - 44000;
    //$total_overweight += $overweight; 
    $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(odbc_result($result, "Date1")));
    $companies[] = odbc_result($result, "String3");
    $weight = odbc_result($result, "Weight1");                                     
    $item['nrplaat'] = odbc_result($result, "String1");
    $item['tptcode'] = odbc_result($result, "String3");
    $item['chrononr'] = odbc_result($result, "String15");
    $item['projectcode'] = odbc_result($result, "String4");
    $item['projectnaam'] = odbc_result($result, "String8");
    $item['1eweging'] = $weight;
    $item['overweighted'] = $overweight;
    $item['date'] = $date;
    $item['2eweging'] = odbc_result($result, "Weight2");
    $item['netto'] = odbc_result($result, "Nett");                                                                     
    switch($weight){
        case($weight > '44000' && $weight <= '44500'):
           $item['class'] = 'lichtgroen';
        case($weight > '44500' && $weight <= '45000'):
           $item['class'] = 'groen';
        case($weight > '45000' && $weight <= '46000'):
           $item['class'] = 'donkergroen';
        case($weight > '46000' && $weight <= '47000'):
           $item['class'] = 'bruingroen';
        case($weight > '47000' && $weight <= '48000'):
           $item['class'] = 'lichtbruin';
        case($weight > '48000' && $weight <= '49000'):
           $item['class'] = 'bruin';
        case($weight > '49000' && $weight <= '50000'):
           $item['class'] = 'lichrood';
        case($weight > '50000'):
           $item['class'] = 'rood';                                                                               
    }                                    
    switch($date){
        case($date > $s_year.'-'.$quart1 && $date <= $s_year.'-'.$quart2):
           $item['quarter'] = '1'; //kwartaal 1
        case($date > $s_year.'-'.$quart2 && $date <= $s_year.'-'.$quart3):
           $item['quarter'] = '2'; ////kwartaal 2
        case($date > $s_year.'-'.$quart3 && $date <= $s_year.'-'.$quart4):
           $item['quarter'] = '3'; ////kwartaal 3
        case($date > $s_year.'-'.$quart4 && $date <= $s_year.'-'.$end):
           $item['quarter'] = '4'; ////kwartaal 4                                        
    }
    //$item['quarter'] = 1; WHEN I DO THIS, ALL RESULTS WILL PRINT OUT!!!
    switch($item['quarter']){
        case '1': 
           print "<tr>\n";
           print "  <td>" . $item['nrplaat'] . "\n";
           print "  <td>" . $item['tptcode'] . "\n";
           print "  <td>" . $item['chrononr'] . "\n";
           print "  <td>" . $item['projectcode'] . "\n";
           print "  <td>" . $item['projectnaam'] . "\n";
           print "  <td>" . $item['1eweging'] . "\n";
           print "  <td>" .  "<span class=\"status\">".$item['class']."</span>" ."\n";
           print "  <td>" . $item['overweighted'] . "\n";
           print "  <td>" . $item['date'] . "\n";
           print "  <td>" . $item['2eweging'] . "\n";
           print "  <td>" . $item['netto'] . "\n";
           print "</tr>\n";
           break;
    }                                    
}
```

Comment: What are the errors you get?

Comment: no errors. i'm pretty sure there is something wrong with my switch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  `break;`

```
case($date > $s_year.'-'.$quart1 && $date <= $s_year.'-'.$quart2):
    $item['quarter'] = '1';
    break;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add a `break;` statement at the end of each case.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's because you don't have `break;` in each switch case.
Try to add some `break;`

See [here](http://php.net/manual/fr/control-structures.switch.php) for switch in php.

Answer (score 0):

You should add 'break' after 'case'. it is very important if you have some 'case'. Please understand the concept of switch statements, you can learn from http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php.

If you have some 'case' and you don't use 'break', it mean the next case will be proceed too. If you using 'break' after 'case', the switch process will finish and not proceed to next case. Maybe you should learn about 'continue' too :)